# Nested Loops Won't Work In Java Program

Tags: java, for-loop

I am writing this program using try-catch exception handling:

```
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] employees = new String[5];
    boolean done1 = false;

    //input and error exception for entering employee names into an array
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {//begin for

        while (!done1)
        {//begin while

            System.out.println("Please enter employee's name: ");
            try
            {//begin try
                employees[i] = keyboard.nextLine();

                if (employees[i].length() == 0)
                    throw new Exception("No name was entered.");

                if (employees[i].length() >= 31)
                    throw new Exception("Name entered contains too many "
                            + "characters");

                for (int check = 0; check < employees[i].length(); check++)
                {//begin for
                    if(Character.isDigit(employees[i].charAt(check)))
                        throw new Exception("Input contains invalid "
                                + "charaters.");
                }//end for

                done1 = true;
            }//end try

            catch (Exception a)
            {//begin catch
                System.out.println("Error: " + a.getMessage());
            }//end catch

        }//end while

    }//end for
```

When I run the program, it kicks out of the for loop and only inputs that first instance of i and the rest are left null. How can I get the program to stay in this loop and have it keep the error checking?

Answer (score 2):

Your `done1` variable remains `true` after the first loop, causing subsequent `while` statements to not enter the loop body.

It is probably better to eliminate the `done1` variable entirely, and use a structure like this:

```
for (...) {
    while (true) {
        try {
            // get user input
            break;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ..
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `done1` back to `false`. Or insert `done1 = false` as the first line in the main `for` cycle.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easiest to simply put another `try catch` block within your `for` loop.  When the exception is thrown, it will use the `for` loop's `catch` and continue iterating.

Something like this:

```
for (int check = 0; check < employees[i].length(); check++)
            {//begin for
                try {
                    if(Character.isDigit(employees[i].charAt(check)))
                        throw new Exception("Input contains invalid "
                                + "charaters.");
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                { //Handle Error
                }
            }//end for
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using Exceptions for this sort of thing at all.

Comment: @Martin Why not?  I could see this being a clean way of separating error handling from the algorithm.  For all we know, later down the road he may want to do logging or something, which can be many lines of code.

Comment: You can just as easily call the Logging methods in situe if you must - but do we really log invalid data that we've discarded? Exceptions are there for Exceptional circumstances.

Comment: While I'm about it - never throw and catch using Exception directly - any other form of exception would also trigger your Catch code here. Always, ALWAYS subclass it.

Comment: Exceptions are there not only for "Exceptional" circumstances, but also a means to organize errors in meaningful ways to the developer. They were the answer to checking for error codes with if statements.  Its just gacky to do a series of if checks just to show a user an error message.  Exceptions are cheap with modern computers, so worrying about performance is just silly.  And while I'm about it, i'll be sure to write a whole bunch of exception classes next time i want to answer a simple question.

Comment: Chad, clearly we're not going to agree - which his fine - free world and all that. Ask yourself what happens in the event an unexpected exception (ie not of your own doing) exception cropping up in your Try block...

Comment: Clealy we are not going to agree Chad - which is fine - free world and all that. Ask yourself what happens should an unexpected (ie not of your own creation) exception crops up in the middle of your Try Block though.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using Exceptions correctly...

Exceptions are a very expensive way of handling logic like this, and your approach in just creating a none specific exception and using it is wrong. Exceptions are designed for dealing with exceptional things that might happen in your programs - resource unavailablility, connection timeouts - that sort of thing.

The problem you are looking at should be approached with mere flow control.

Hope this helps...

Martin.

Ps. Your code, with the Exceptions replaced by something a little more reasonable, might look like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SOExample {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] employees = new String[5];
        boolean done1 = false;
        String strMessage = "";
        //input and error exception for entering employee names into an array
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {//begin for
            done1 = false;

            while (!done1)
            {//begin while
                strMessage="";
                System.out.println("Please enter employee's name: ");
                employees[i] = keyboard.nextLine();

                if (employees[i].length() == 0)
                    strMessage = "No name was entered.";

                if (employees[i].length() >= 31)
                    strMessage = "Name entered contains too many "
                            + "characters";
                if (strMessage == ""){
                    for (int check = 0; check < employees[i].length(); check++)
                    {//begin for
                        if(Character.isDigit(employees[i].charAt(check))){
                            strMessage = "Input contains invalid "
                                    + "charaters.";
                            break;
                        }
                    }//end for
                }

                done1 = (strMessage == "");
                if (!done1){
                    System.out.println("Error: " + strMessage);
                }

            }//end while

        }//end for

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

the first time you enter the while loop the !done1 expressions evaluates to true since done1 is false. toward the end you set done1 to true. when you evaluate !done1 in order to perform the loop again, the expression is now false since you set done1 to true in the first pass.